# Annotation with generic ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

i have a model `Article` which goes on like this.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    body = RichTextField()
```

I store comments on article in a table with a `GenericForeignKey` as I wanted to use the commenting feature on models of different types, like this:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

How can I find the most commented `Article`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the ['reversing generic keys'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations) section of the documentation

You add a `GenericRelation` to your `Article` model to make reversing it easier:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.generic import GenericRelation
class Article(...):
    ...
    comments = GenericRelation(Comment)
```

then you can simply [use the `annotate` model method to find the article with the most comments and order them them](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-by):

```
from django.db.models import Count
...
articles = Article.objects.all().annotate(comment_count=Count("comments")).order_by("comment_count)
if articles: 
    most_commented = articles[0]
```